# HAProxy redirect port 8080 CentOS 7- "503 Service Unavailable"

Tags: centos7, haproxy

I have been trying to redirect to port 8080 and get an error "503 Service Unavailable. No server is available to handle this request."

[image]

Below is my haproxy configuration file

> ```
> global
> log         127.0.0.1 local2
>
> chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
> pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
> maxconn     4000
> user        haproxy
> group       haproxy
> daemon
>
> # turn on stats unix socket
> stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
>
>
> defaults
> mode                    http
> log                     global
> option                  httplog
> option                  dontlognull
> option http-server-close
> option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
> option                  redispatch
> retries                 3
> timeout http-request    10s
> timeout queue           1m
> timeout connect         10s
> timeout client          1m
> timeout server          1m
> timeout http-keep-alive 10s
> timeout check           10s
> maxconn                 3000
>
> frontend  main
> mode http
> option httplog
> bind 0.0.0.0:5000
> bind 0.0.0.0:8070
> #option http-server-close
> #option forwardfor
> #default_backend app-main
> option httpclose
> option forwardfor
> acl is_legacy        dst_port 8070
> use_backend legacy if is_legacy
> default_backend application
>
> backend application
> mode http
> option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
> server webserver my_webserver_ip:80 check
>
>
> backend legacy
> mode http
> option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
> server apiserver my_webserver_ip:8080 check
> ```

I have been able to redirect 5000 to 80 port -> to show default nginx page.
But,failed to redirect 8070 to 8080 port (Example for: http://www.mywebsite.com:8070/swagger-ui.html ).

I want to use the same webserver and redirect to different ports.

Can anyone let me know what configuration is missing. Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Check the haproxy log. Check if the backend server is up.

Comment: I am configuring haproxy and webserver on same instance.

Comment: I have updated the question with image.